An exercise on Haar measures in Lang's Real and Functional Analysis book
I'm trying to understand the statement of the following exercise (Lang, Real and Functional Analysis, page 326):

Identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue (Haar) measure on $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, and let $z$ denote the general element of $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $d\mu(\alpha z)=|\alpha|^2d\mu(z)$, as functionals on $C_c(\mathbb{C})=C_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

In the book, the author defines the functional $d\mu$ ($\mu$ a Borel measure on a locally compact space $X$) as the map $f\mapsto \int f\,d\mu$, where $f\in C_c(X)$ ($C_c(X)$ is the space of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support). My doubts are as follows:

From the definition of $d\mu$, I understand that $d\mu(\alpha z)=\int f\,d\mu$, where $f(z)=\alpha z$. Now, $f$ has support equal to $\mathbb{C}$, which is not compact. How can we then define $d\mu(\alpha z)$? Moreover, the map $f:z\mapsto \alpha z$ does not have values in $\mathbb{R}$, so it wouldn't be an element of $C_c(\mathbb{C})$ (even if the support were compact). If I restrict this function to points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha z\in\mathbb{R}$, then, writing $\alpha=a+bi$ and $z=x+yi$, this set corresponds to the region in the complex plane where $ay+bx=0$. Even in this case, it seems to me that the function wouldn't have compact support. So, what does the notation $d\mu(\alpha z)$ mean?
My second question is about the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$: We are identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can define the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and thus we can talk about the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$, right?
Finally, how do we verify that $d\mu(\alpha z)=|\alpha|^2d\mu(z)$?


The definition of $d\mu$ gives that $d \mu$ maps a given $f$ to $\int f d\mu$. To show that $d\mu(\alpha z) = |\alpha|d \mu(z)$ as functionals, you pick an arbitrary $f \in C_c(\mathbb{C})$ and check if $\int f d \mu(\alpha z) = \int f |\alpha|^2 d \mu(z).$ So you see the measure $d\mu(\alpha z)$ as a functional on $C_c(\mathbb{C})$ by integrating functions with compact support against that measure.
